# How can I determine who is blocking port 25 from the internet?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, nas, smtp, dmz

I'm flummoxed.

I've bought a domain name through 'freehostia.com' - and I've setup the MX records to point to my DDNS based local SMTP/POP3 server which I'm running on a Synology NAS box.

I've configured my router to turn off firewall at this point, as well as configured it to simply forward everything to my NAS box using DMZ forwarding.

Locally - on my NAT LAN, I can test the SMTP server using telnet or SMTP Diag Tool - which provides a very nice log of the I/O.

I'm getting expected responses - 220 xxxxxxxxxx ESMTP Postfix, EHLO, etc.

But if I go to someplace on the outside network - say to https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

And then do an SMTP test on my server from there - I get timeouts every single time.

It isn't as nice with showing any sort of a log - but I think there's no log to show - the attempted connection to port 25 just times out every time.

I've removed all security from my SMTP server and disabled the firewall in my router - done all I can to make it as dumb and simple as possible - just to see if I can get anything whatsoever to get through.

I have also tested my email server using roundcube webmail (also hosted on my NAS box) - and locally - that works great!  I have even tested sending myself an email and that all works just dandy.

But if I try to send an email from a legit outside source - gmail or yahoo - I get a "failed to send for 12 hrs, giving up"

Outgoing emails from my email server I see being rejected from google and others because I've not turned on DKIM and other security measures - or I am in the process of configuring all of that properly (I now have SSL certificates for my mail server) - so that's reasonable.

but incoming - it just appears as if my NAS box never hears a peap from the outside world.

I read some forums that indicated that Comcast could be blocking me - but I'm not using their equipment - I have a simple TP Link TC-7610 DOCSIS 3.0 modem - and I was able to connect to it earlier and verify that it has no firewall options in it at all.  It's a simple pass-through modem, as I expected.  Comcast indicated that if you have their equipment - they always configure it to block port 25 - but in my case - my own equipment cannot be configured by them.  And since the TC-7610 has no firewall in it at all - how can it possibly be blocking port 25?!

It's also driving me nuts that I can get to my NAS box in many other ways - it runs its own web server interface at port 5000/50001, which is what attempts to contact my network on port 80 are redirected to automatically.  Perfect.  There are other services running there - I just added SSH on port 22.  I can't test that one form outside (or I don't know of a way to do that just now) - but internally I can see that's working.

I don't see how freehostia could possibly be doing anything - all they're managing are a couple of MX records (and eventually TXT records for the DKIM and the like).

And if I test my server via a DDNS name (that I also have running - clearly not hosted by freehostia) - I get the same "dead line" timeout issue - nothing appears to get to my NAS box.

Is it even remotely possible that my NAS box itself refuses all connections from outside of the LAN?!!!

Help!

Comment: If Comcast is blocking you they're doing on equipment within their network. It wouldn't matter who's equipment you have installed at your location; the block would still have its effect.

Comment: The friendly fellow I talked to at Comcast (which took me about 2.5 hrs to get through to) said he'd unblock the port - but then said he couldn't due to not having their equipment - which made me think "duh!  I guess it could be my modem!  hadn't thought of that!"  But after hanging up - of course I looked it up - it has no firewall - no port forwarding or blocking abilities. >:(
So - maybe I have to push through to Tier 2 or Tier 3 support to find someone who's competent?

Comment: You may use the [MX LookupTool](https://mxtoolbox.com/) for deep testing.

Comment: !@#$ Yes - it HAS to be Comcast - I just changed my SMTP server on my NAS to use port 2525 - and MXLookupTool - forcing that to use 2525 - shows an immediate log!  !@#$!@ >:(  Comcast!!!! >:(

Comment: Take it up with Comcast or use another port.

Comment: if I want to fully handle my incoming mail from other servers in the world - how would they know to use a different port?

Comment: This is typical for a Comcast customer on their residential plans. They don't want you hosting a mail server. They don't do this to their commercial plan customers.

Comment: Not just a mail server.  They want the internet to be a one-way pipe: from them to you.  The whole idea of our putting up our own servers to create public web pages or other services, is just anathema.  We are supposed to be *consumers*.  Now that the US has lost net neutrality, watch for this to get progressively worse.

Comment: Comcast has been doing that since I was in high school. It has nothing to do with net neutrality... Keep the political b.s to yourself, it has no place here.